# SWI-Prolog how to reload workspace?

Tags: prolog, reload, workspace

I am using standard editor that came with SWI-Prolog. I would like to reload workspace, so that all prior assertions and knowledge base would disappear. Is there short cut for it? I can surely close and re-open editor, but wonder if there is faster way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to reload workspace, so that all prior assertions and knowledge base would disappear.

IMO to clean a complex environment is not really doable in SWI-Prolog. The database is global, by design, and removing parts of a loaded state is not easy.

But you can store the step used when setup your workspace in `~/.swiplrc`, to reconstruct your experience when (re)starting the environment. For instance, in my own, I have

```
...
user:file_search_path(carlo, '/home/carlo/prolog').
user:file_search_path(scxml, carlo(scxml)).

d :- cd('/home/carlo/prolog'), portray_text(true), edit(read_trace_php).
...
```

Then, if I 'query' `?- d.`, SWI-Prolog opens an editor on `read_trace_php.pl`.
If I wrote in my .swiplrc the `directive`

```
:- cd('/home/carlo/prolog'), portray_text(true), edit(read_trace_php).
```

then any time I launched swipl I would get the editor ready.

Facts of the form

```
user:file_search_path(scxml, carlo(scxml)).
```

are handy to define the 'include path' required by your project.

You can edit your .swiplrc from `> Settings > User init file ...`